# How do i correctly position these items horizontally in flutter to avoid overflow?

Tags: flutter, dart, containers, uitabbar

I have a list of items that are responsible for a tab bar design, i want to make all the sizedboxes display at a go and not overflow horizontally.

I will give my code for better clarification.

This is what i could come up with after over an hour of tussle:

[image: My design]

And this is what i am expecting

[image: Expected design]

I will give my code snippets of the view below.

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class JobsHeaderWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const JobsHeaderWidget({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<JobsHeaderWidget> createState() => _JobsHeaderWidgetState();
}

class _JobsHeaderWidgetState extends State<JobsHeaderWidget> {
  List<String> items = [
    "All",
    "Critical",
    "Open",
    "Closed",
    "Overdue",
  ];

  int current = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            'Jobs',
            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Text(
                'View Insights  ',
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    color: Color(0xff3498DB),
                    fontSize: 12,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
              Icon(
                Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                color: Color(0xff3498DB),
                size: 12,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          filterJobs()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget filterJobs() {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          /// CUSTOM TABBAR
          SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 60,
            child: ListView.builder(
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: items.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            current = index;
                          });
                        },
                        child: AnimatedContainer(
                          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: current == index
                                ? Color(0xff34495E)
                                : Color(0xffF5F5F5),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11),
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 5, bottom: 5),
                              child: Text(
                                items[index],
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                    fontSize: 10,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    color: current == index
                                        ? Colors.white
                                        : Colors.grey),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }),
          ),

          // Builder(
          //   builder: (context) {
          //     switch (current) {
          //       case 0:
          //         return AllNotificationItemsView();
          //       case 1:
          //         return JobsNotificationItemsView();
          //       case 2:
          //         return MessagesNotificationItemsView();
          //       case 3:
          //         return CustomersNotificationItemsView();
          //       default:
          //         return SizedBox.shrink();
          //     }
          //   },
          // )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: By the way, returning widgets in functions is not recommended. `filterJobs()` should be its own widget

Comment: @UnicornsOnLSD thanks for the heads up, i tried extracting it but it keeps saying "reference to an enclosing class method can not be extracted"

Comment: you could use expanded widget

Comment: @tesseract If the automatic thing in vscode isn't working then you may have to rip it out manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for overflow is List View Builder. Remove it and add a Row widget instead. Iterate the list item in it and you will get your desired output.

Full Code : -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Image',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const JobsHeaderWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class JobsHeaderWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const JobsHeaderWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<JobsHeaderWidget> createState() => _JobsHeaderWidgetState();
}

class _JobsHeaderWidgetState extends State<JobsHeaderWidget> {
  List<String> items = [
    "All",
    "Critical",
    "Open",
    "Closed",
    "Overdue",
  ];

  int current = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10, top: 5),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: Container(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 610, maxHeight: 100),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: IntrinsicWidth(
              child: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) ...[
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            current = i;
                          });
                        },
                        child: AnimatedContainer(
                          height: 40,
                          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 5, bottom: 5),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: current == i
                                ? const Color(0xff34495E)
                                : const Color(0xffF5F5F5),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11),
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              items[i],
                              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                  fontSize: 19,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  color: current == i
                                      ? Colors.white
                                      : Colors.grey),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output : -

[image]

Comment: try to resize the screen size, it will be overflowing. your design is not responsive

Comment: yes i am, try to copy your code into dartpad.dev, and try to resize the screen size https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj1kL.png check this out

Comment: yep, its working but when your device is bigger it mean your appbar is way to big for a user to see. try to run on chrome and try to make the screen size bigger, your text and the button will become so big and is not a good design for user to see it

Comment: when the design become bigger the button will have a max size for it so when display is bigger the design will stay at start https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG5Q5.png

Comment: Thank you @Ramji looks like i'll go with this quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

Hey there for making the appbar not overflowing, you must use expanded widget. try to wrap your gestureDetector or whatever widget that you create for making the design for each listview child like this

```dart
 Expanded(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      current = i;
                    });
                  },
                  child: AnimatedContainer(
                    height: 40,
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 5, bottom: 5),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: current == i
                          ? const Color(0xff34495E)
                          : const Color(0xffF5F5F5),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11),
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        items[i],
                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            fontSize: 12,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: current == i ? Colors.white : Colors.grey),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

as you can see when you doing this the design will look like this
[image]

the text inside of the design would gone because of overflowing issue, you can change the `text` widget into this widget https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text

this is the snipet

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, right: 5, top: 20),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) ...[
                  Expanded(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          current = i;
                        });
                      },
                      child: AnimatedContainer(
                        height: 40,
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 5.0, right: 5.0, top: 5, bottom: 5),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: current == i
                              ? const Color(0xff34495E)
                              : const Color(0xffF5F5F5),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: AutoSizeText(
                            items[i],
                            maxLines: 1,
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                fontSize: 12,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                color:
                                    current == i ? Colors.white : Colors.grey),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
```

but surely the text would be some of big and some of small look like this, and this is the result
[image]
[image]
[image]