# How to make this design

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to make this design in flutter I have tried in row, but it's going to overflow. So, you
can help me to make this using any another way!

[image]

Comment: Please attach the minimum executable or attempted code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i correctly position these items horizontally in flutter to avoid overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75041573/how-do-i-correctly-position-these-items-horizontally-in-flutter-to-avoid-overflo)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, writing Chips with Containers like other answers suggest is not necessary.  Because you actually have chips widgets in Flutter. Please check them out, they are well documented and have examples provided.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FilterChip-class.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ChoiceChip-class.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputChip-class.html

Answer (score 0):

here is the exact coding , I used in my project, it might help u...

change according to your design..

```
class HomeScreen_Coffee extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen_Coffee({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen_Coffee> createState() => _HomeScreen_CoffeeState();
}

class _HomeScreen_CoffeeState extends State<HomeScreen_Coffee> {
  List<String> titles=['All','Fav','Popular','Trending'
  ];

  int selectedindex=0;



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: 
            Container(
              height: 40,
              child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: titles.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                    return CoffeeTile(name: titles[index], ontap: (){
                      selectedindex=index;
                      setState(() {

                      });
                    },isselected: selectedindex==index,);
                  }),
            ),
           
        ));
  }
}
```

```
class CoffeeTile extends StatelessWidget {

  final String name;
  final bool isselected;
  final VoidCallback ontap;

  const CoffeeTile({Key? key,required this.name,this.isselected=false,required this.ontap}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: ontap,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white12,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),

          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(name.toString(),style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,color: isselected?Colors.orange:Colors.grey,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
            ),),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I like your answer but I want that If u click on any button it should be redirect on that page. So, how I can do that. and It should be selected option. So, please help me on that.

Answer (score 0):

[image: here is some picture of how this code will works]

define variable for selected Index.

```
int selectedIndex = 0;
```

Just Put in your widget

```
SizedBox(
          height: 40,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 20,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  selectedIndex = index;
                  setState(() {});
                },
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: selectedIndex == index ? Colors.blueAccent.shade100 : Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: selectedIndex == index ? 12 : 10, horizontal: selectedIndex == index ? 18 : 15),
                  child: Text("Text $index", style: TextStyle(color: selectedIndex == index ? Colors.white : Colors.grey, fontSize: selectedIndex == index ? 15 : 12)),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        )
```

**I Hope this will solve your issue.**

Comment: I like your answer but I want that If u click on any button it should be redirect on that page. So, how I can do that. and It should be selected option. So, please help me on that.

Comment: Yes you have to just put navigation's materialPageRoute in onTap.